# Change the orientation of view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, orientation

I want to change a view's orientation as and when it is displayed.
For Example:
Whenever the user clicks a button a new view is displayed to the user. Whatever may be the orientation,I want to display this view in Landscape mode.
Any Ideas.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function the in the new view to change the Orientation to landscape mode.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientationUIIn terfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight );
    }
```

Comment: Still it displays the View in Portrait mode only. When the phone is tilted then it changes to Landscape mode. But i want to change it to Landscape mode when the view is loaded.;)

Answer (score 2):

Use this function in your class.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations

   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||                        
   interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientationUIIn terfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight );
    }
```